# Get the ArrayList from TXT file

Tags: android, arraylist, widget

Everyone. Good morning.

This is a android widget. I'm using this code. I just wanted to get the `ArrayList` from a external file as .TXT (saved in `assets` Folder) instead of getting quotes' list from the java file. But there is something wrong in this code. It isn't reading the "`quote.txt`" file that is in "`assets` folder".

This is my code:

```
   public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = UpdateWidgetService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart started");

    // Create some random data
    Random random = new Random();

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {

        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            List<String> qList = getListFromTxtFile("quote.txt");
            int nextInt = random.nextInt(qList.size());

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, qList.get(nextInt));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

public List<String> getListFromTxtFile(String txtFileName){

//  File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// Get the text file
// File file = new File(sdcard,txtFileName);

AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

List<String> qList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Read text from file

try {
    InputStream is = am.open("quote.txt");
          //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

     // get data in text file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

       qList.add(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
return qList;

}
}
```

Comment: what's the exception it is throwing?

Comment: please share the logcat logs...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
   AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("quote.txt");
   FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Comment: Where I put this? I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Where I put this code, Ics? Within "Try {"